# Why does it print the session id instead of the element path?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Code:

```
FindComment = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'commented')]").parent
print(FindComment)
```

Output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="99sf9sfjSIFSf-f9sf(JSFsfsfs")>
```

Not sure why it prints this. I want it to print the actual element path

Answer (score 0):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

> **parent**

> Internal reference to the WebDriver instance this element was
> found from.

You cannot find the locator from webelement

The only thing you could do is

```
     element.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Comment: How would I get the element path tho? Want it to look like this: /html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/div. I am also getting the same issue without .parent

Comment: element.get_attribute("outerHTML")

Comment: This is the only thing you could do , you cannot get the xpath

Comment: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5520